# How can i recalculate css properties after animation-duration property is done?

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I'm trying to obtain a bubble-rising effect and so good it looks ok. I randomly atribute css properties like height, width or animation-duration with JQuery. But i wonder if i could recalculate some of the properties after that animation-duration is done.

```
for(var i=1; i<=7; i++)
   {
    var randBottom = Math.ceil(Math.random()*200); 
    var randWidth = Math.ceil(Math.random()*50)+20;
    var randHeight = Math.ceil(Math.random()*100)+200;
    var oceanWidth= $("#ocean").width();
    var randLeft= Math.ceil(Math.random()*(oceanWidth-randWidth));
    var randDuration = Math.ceil(Math.random()*7)+2; 
     var cssObj = {
        'bottom' : randBottom+'px',
         'height' : randHeight+'px',
         'width' : randWidth+'px',
         'left' : randLeft+'px',
         'animation-duration': randDuration+'s',
         '-moz-animation-duration': randDuration+'s',
         '-webkit-animation-duration' :randDuration+'s',
         '-o-animation-duration':randDuration+'s'
        };
    $("#bubble"+i).css(cssObj);
   }
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/dZJJu/2/) is a sample of my work in progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought this would give you what you were looking for, but it seems like keeping css keyframes duration and javascript timing difficult to sync.

Are you willing to change animation to `jQuery.animate()` instead?

```
for(var i=1; i<=7; i++)
{
    randomizeBubble(i)
}

function randomizeBubble(i)
{
    var randBottom = Math.ceil(Math.random()*200); 
    var randWidth = Math.ceil(Math.random()*50)+20;
    var randHeight = Math.ceil(Math.random()*100)+200;
    var oceanWidth= $("#ocean").width();
    var randLeft= Math.ceil(Math.random()*(oceanWidth-randWidth));
    var randDuration = Math.ceil(Math.random()*7)+2; 
     var cssObj = {
        'bottom' : randBottom+'px',
         'height' : randHeight+'px',
         'width' : randWidth+'px',
         'left' : randLeft+'px',
         'animation-duration': randDuration+'s',
         '-moz-animation-duration': randDuration+'s',
         '-webkit-animation-duration' :randDuration+'s',
         '-o-animation-duration':randDuration+'s'
        };
    $("#bubble"+i).css(cssObj);

    setTimeout(function(){randomizeBubble(i);}, randDuration * 1000)
}
```

- [jsFiddle, sync failure](http://jsfiddle.net/X5teA/)
- [jsFiddle, `jQuery.animate()`](http://jsfiddle.net/nzqHs/5/)